# Can I use 'bekommen' equal to 'become' in some cases

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can I say

> Ich bekam die Inkarnation des Todes.

and thus use *bekommen* equal to *become* in the English language? I am certain I read this sentence somewhere in an old text but I am not sure anymore.

Answer (score 8):

That's a well known **mistake**.

*Bekommen* does **not** mean become.

Bekommen could be translated to "get" or "receive".

Become means "werden" in Germany.

Comment: And also in Austria.

Comment: Let's just go the whole mile and say *in German*, i.e. anywhere it's spoken.

Comment: in Switzerland only as long as we try to speak "proper German". The word *bekommen* in Swiss German is *übercho*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can say it, because you can say everything you want. But it has not the meaning that you want to express.

> Ich bekam die Inkarnation des Todes.
>   I've got the incarnation of death.

This means, that you received something (maybe in a box with a pretty bow) that is called “the incarnation of death”. Probably it's a book with this title.

---

The English word “become” and the German word “bekommen” are what linguists call “false friends”. They never mean the same.

***English* “To become something” = *German* “etwas werden”**
“To become something” is **never never never** “etwas bekommen”. **NEVER!**

***German* “etwas bekommen” = *English* “To get something”**
“etwas bekommen” is **never never never** “to become something”. **NEVER!**

> Tom asks: “Can I **become** a lawyer?” = Tom fragt: „Kann ich ein Anwalt **werden**?“ (Tom is 15 years old and talking with his parents about what will be his profession in 10 years)
>
> Tom fragt: „Kann ich einen Anwalt **bekommen**?“ = Tom asks: “Can I **get** a lawyer?” (Tom is accused of having committed a crime, he want assistance from a lawyer.)

But there are cases where “to get” translates into “werden”:

> I am getting older. = Ich werde älter.

But never, never, never is “become” the same as “bekommen”.

Comment: «But never, never, never is “become” the same as “bekommen”»: Not true. It shares [meaning 2.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/become) with its German cognate.

Comment: +1 to Carsten. Also, it is "lawyer". "Layer" bedeutet "Schicht, Ebene"

Comment: @CarstenS: Not true? Then please give an example (in both languages) where the English *become* has to be same meaning as the German *bekommen*.

Comment: „Der B-Promi-Status bekam Potter nicht.“

Comment: Ok, actually it is not exactly the same, but close enough. My main point is that you fail to write anything interesting. The question lets me think that the OP already knows that *bekommen* generally does not mean *werden*, so the only information that your answer adds is **NEVER NEVER NEVER**, and that in a quite lengthy fashion and without any sources.

Comment: @CarstenS: Feel free to write a better answer.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast How come this sentence is valid then: "Für den öffentlichen Gebrauch bekam Skipjack eine Treuhand-Hintertür eingebaut und wurde in einen Chip namens "Capstone" integriert." - The "bekam" can be exchanged for "wurde" without any change of meaning.

Comment: I admit though, that the "wurde" is not equivalent to "become" in this context. But still "become" is translated with "werden", thus there is a connection for OP maybe?

Comment: @Sim: Wrong. »Jemand *bekommt* etwas gemacht« is not the same as »Jemand *wird* etwas gemacht«. The second is a grammatical wrong sentence. A correct sentence would be: »Etwas *wird* gemacht« or »Etwas *wird* für jemand gemacht.« Now the translations: »Jemand *bekommt* etwas gemacht« = »somebody *gets* something done« (Ich bekomme meine Haare geschnitten = I get my hair cut). »Etwas wird für jemand gemacht« = »Something is done for somebody« (Die Tür wurde für mich gestrichen. = The door was painted for me.)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what i meant:"Für den öffentlichen Gebrauch bekam Skipjack eine Treuhand-Hintertür eingebaut und wurde in einen Chip namens "Capstone" integriert" is quite equal to "Für den öffentlichen Gebrauch wurde Skipjack eine Treuhand-Hintertür eingebaut und wurde in einen Chip namens "Capstone" integriet". Sure there is/might be a deeper nuance between the two versions, but they can both be used and convey the same meaning, and I'd actually bet that the usage of 'bekam' is due to the else occuring redundancy of 'wurde'.